# Chemical Analyses

Tags: t-test, chemometrics

We have two groups of chemical sample results reporting the concentration of a dissolved substance.  If I want to compare the two groups I can just carry out a simple t-test.  This will say whether their means are equal allowing for the variance in each group.  However the labs report each result with an individual range of uncertainty which is not taken into account with this test.  Is there a way to include this extra source of variability when comparing the means?  If the ROU is very small compared to the difference in means then the test result could be very different to where the ROU is large.

Comment: Could you please make an example of the way they report the result with a individual range of uncertainty? Just to understand better. Like a confidence interval you say?

Comment: The sample results are reported as, say, 0.69 ± 0.01 where the 0.01 is a figure derived from the known uncertainties in the method used for the analysis.

Comment: I am not expert about the specific methods used in the field, but l would suggest you could look at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)

Comment: Yes confidence intervals may be the alternative way of thinking about this that I need.  I can use each result in a group to estimate the mean for that group and use the ROUs to give an estimate of the variance for that mean (the ROUs are 2 sd).  I can then carry out a t-test based on the two means, the pooled estimate of the common variance (it's reasonable to assume that the two sets of results would have the same variance) and df.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a great help, I have to admit, as I am not into the specific subject.. but that was the closest and most logical thing I could think of..

Comment: If the range of uncertainty reflects random variability of each individual result, then that will show up in the sample variances used for the t test and I don't see that any adjustment in t test results is needed. However if ROU means that on a given day the measurement system may be $\pm 0.01$ out of adjustment (in one direction or the other), affecting all measurements that day in the same way, then you need to try to understand consequences of that.

Comment: As @Fr1 indicated, and you already knew, just do the two sample t test with each standard deviation equal to half its respective ROU. This assumes the ROU equals 2 times the sample standard deviation. I say this because it looks like you are dealing with data from an undergrad chemistry lab (or similar) and this is what I expected my students to do.

Comment: @EdV thanks for the confirmation